# Passing 'animated' text to js

Tags: javascript, css, text, typography, blending

I have @keyframes text animation is css (text is changing with :after method)
I need to pass that text to javascript to chnage the blending mode for each letter (thanks to Mostafa Hassan I know how to do it now!)
Not sure how I can grab the text that was altered with :after method in css though. Any help?

```
<p class="blend text-animate" blend-mode="difference" data="Blend"></p>
```

```
.text-animate{
  font-size:280px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: -60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: aquamarine;
  animation-name: blending;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text-animate:after{
  animation-name: blending;
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  content: "";
}

@keyframes blending {
0% {content: "NoBlend"; color: aquamarine;}
50% {content: "Keyframes"; color: royalblue;}
100% {content: "NoBlend"; color: aquamarine;}
}
```

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName("blend");
let text = element[0].getAttribute("data");
let blendMode = element[0].getAttribute("blend-mode");
for(let chr of text) 
  element[0].innerHTML += "<span style='mix-blend-mode: "+blendMode+"' > "+chr+"</span>";
```

Comment: after is not a method, it is a pseudo element. It is having absolutely no effect in the given code. Please describe the effect you want in more detail.

Comment: Haha, sorry, pls forgive my vocabrurary... a lot to learn! 
I'm replacing the text with @keyframes animation. I want to pass whatever text is in innerHTML to Javascript. (in js Im' separating text to individual letters and applying different blending mode but assume it doesn't matter too much here)

Comment: There is no text in the p element's innerHTML and that is the only element shown. Is there more? Actually what is happening is the other way round, the text in the data attribute is having HTML altered and is being put into the innerHTML so I'm confused.

Comment: Can you please explain more you goal, despite the code above, just the idea you want to achieve, as I am not getting you

Comment: Sorry trying to find the right words but struggling... I need to have text that is changing every few seconds but the individual letters within this word overlap with a  certain blending mode. I was trying to do the change of the text in css but maybe it is better to do it in js?

Comment: I got your point, okay imagine that, you have three words that have blend modes, put each word in div tag and make them position absolute, i.e above each other, then with JavaScript show each div individually for 3 second, and do some transition, and show the second one and so on, etc... i will try to provide you with an example Asap